# Expand vim split

Tags: vim

I've have splits open in vim which look like:

```
----------------
|  A |  B |  C |
----------------
|  D |    E    |
----------------
```

I'd like to expand the `C` split such that my splits look like:

```
----------------
|  A |  B |    |
----------|  C |
|  D |  E |    |
----------------
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press `<C-W>L` in window C. See `:h CTRL-W_L`.

Comment: awesome! follow up question: what if I wanted to expand `B` instead of `C` and push `E` under `C`?  ie: I want `B` to take up the full height of the screen in the middle of the screen.

Comment: That would be trickier. I think it would need a combination of hiding buffers with `:hide`, splitting windows and then loading the hidden buffers back into the new splits with `:bp` and similar.

Comment: For many editing tasks you just want one of the buffers big so you can see what you're editing. You can use `<C-W>_` and `<C-W>|` for this, then `<C-W>=` to lay the windows out again.